# How to Change Thu 1 Dec format to php date format

Tags: php

I am doing php parsing and getting date like Thu 1 Dec and I want to store it in database and my date column in database is of DATE type, so when I store this in database, it inserts 0000-00-00 because of improper format. How can I convert it into proper format?

Comment: Well you need a year to start with

Comment: You may use Corcel to parse this time domain to generate what ever you want.

Comment: Change field type from DATE to varchar then you will  be able to store any format of date in database.

Comment: @user247217 Sure, even dates like "tomorrow" or "pink".

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález  i know this is not proper way but i can handle it on frontend using php date functions

Comment: Please give me a hint how I can convert it proper format

Answer (score 0):

To format the date properly, use something like this

```
$Date = Date('c', strtotime($Date))
```

The date has to be something strtotime can understand, but strtotime can understand a lot.